# Open a project in a new window in IntelliJ after "accidentally" clicking remember decision

Tags: intellij-idea

I wanted to open a new project in a separate window in IntelliJ and I "accidentally" clicked "Remember this decision and don't ask again" and clicked "open in the same window"!

Since I have more than one project it is getting really annoying to switch! 
Where could I change this setting?

Comment: Quite an unintuitive solution, they must change so it asks for a confirm at least, seeing that is unsearchable via Shift+Alt+A & trying to manually search.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

It can be changed in in File | Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Project Opening (or, before version 15, File | Settings/Preferences | General | Project Opening)

Comment: Thank you, these settings are so well-hidden, impossible to find without a SO search :-)

Answer (score 33):

In addition to the previous answers by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22062026/2018047) and [Trailing Slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216249/2018047), `Ctrl`-clicking on a project in the "recently opened" list (`File` > `Reopen Project`) will open it in a new window - at least on Windows, running IntelliJ 14.0.3 Community edition. Useful if you only want to open a new window from time to time... :)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with File > Open...

Comment: Thanks! This is what is really needed. A default, that can be manually overridden when needed when altering the default.

Comment: Not working for me on Mac with 2018.2 :(. I'm using the "Mac" key bindings, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 15):

In IDEA 14 and IDEA 15, this can be found in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings -> Project Opening.

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.x you can find it by path:

```
IntelliJ IDEA
  -> Preferences
    -> Appearance & Behavior
      -> System Settings : Project Opening preferences
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer already there, But I like to give short cut.

1. Press **Ctrl + Alt + S**.
2. Write **'System Settings'** in search box and press enter.
3. Open **'System Settings'** in results below.
4. You can see **'Project Opening'** there is three options, select which way you want.

   > Not only for this for anything, search with word works faster than navigating all the tabs. For example if you want to change font size, search for font. You can see where and all it there.

> Note: Some times it searching word not show in search results below. But it will appear if you open tabs in the search result. Like above, if you search **'Project Opening'**, it not appearing in result below, but it there in **'System Settings'**.

Comment: Don't rely on shortcuts, because these are system dependent. For example on my Mac it's ⌘ + `,`

Answer (score 3):

In Intellij 2022 it has changed to `File | Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Project`, then in the `Open Project in`, select `Ask`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow step->

1. File
2. Settings
3. Appearance and Behaviour
4. System setting
5. Under project setting chooses New Window "Radio Button".
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3csEX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl** + **alt** + **s** (settings)

Write **Manage Projects**

Is it **Open Recent** / **Manage Projects**...

**Click** on it and **bind** it

Comment: Don't rely on shortcuts, because these are system dependent. For example on my Mac it's ⌘ + `,`